# Tikzpicture within figure being rendered above text even with [H] or [h!]

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning, tikz-trees

I have the following latex file which I am compiling with LuaLatex on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Pictures
\usepackage{amsmath} % Maths formulas
\usepackage{float} % Figure placement
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Pretty graphs
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\title{Assignment 1}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle
\section{}
\subsection*{a.}
In the following table, the first row corresponds to the setup step of Dijkstra's algorithm and the other rows correspond to the state during each iteration of the for loop in the algorithm.
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
            \textbf{$\#$} & \textbf{T} & \textbf{$u_1$} & \textbf{$u_2$} & \textbf{$u_3$} & \textbf{$u_4$} & \textbf{$u_5$} & \textbf{$u_6$} & \textbf{$u_7$} & \textbf{$P_1$} & \textbf{$P_2$} & \textbf{$P_3$} & \textbf{$P_4$} & \textbf{$P_5$} & \textbf{$P_6$} & \textbf{$P_7$}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{0} & \textbf{$\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{1} & \textbf{$\{3,4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{1}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{2} & \textbf{$\{4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{3} & \textbf{$\{4,5,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{4} & \textbf{$\{4,5\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\{5\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

This is the resulting spanning tree:
\newline
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \tikz \graph[tree layout, nodes={circle,draw}]
          {
            1 -- {2,3};
            2 -- 6 -- 5;
            3 -- 7 -- 4;
         };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It yields this result and I don't understand why:

[image]

I tried giving `[h]`, `[h!]` and `[H]` to the figure float but I still can't get it to render below the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you don't want a `table` environment, that might send the `tabular` somewhere else.

Second, `\tikz` inside `\begin{tikzpicture}` is wrong.

I also suggest `array` instead of `tabular`, so you can simplify a lot the input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Pictures
\usepackage{amsmath} % Maths formulas
\usepackage{float} % Figure placement
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Pretty graphs
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\title{Assignment 1}

\begin{document}

\section{Some title}
\subsection*{a.}

In the following table, the first row corresponds to the setup step of 
Dijkstra's algorithm and the other rows correspond to the state during 
each iteration of the for loop in the algorithm.

\begin{center}
\boldmath
$\begin{array}{c*{15}{|c}}
\# & T & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 & u_5 & u_6 & u_7 & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7\\
\hline
0 & \{2,3,4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
1 & \{3,4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & \infty & \infty & 6 & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
\hline
2 & \{4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 12 & \infty & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
3 & \{4,5,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 12 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
4 & \{4,5\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
5 & \{5\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}$
\end{center}

This is the resulting spanning tree:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[
    tree layout,
    nodes={circle,draw}
  ]{
    1 -- {2,3};
    2 -- 6 -- 5;
    3 -- 7 -- 4;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also load `\usepackage{booktabs}` and change the code for the table to

```
\begin{center}
\boldmath
$\begin{array}{c*{15}{c}}
\toprule
\# & T & u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 & u_5 & u_6 & u_7 & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7\\
\midrule
0 & \{2,3,4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & \infty & \infty & \infty & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \{3,4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & \infty & \infty & 6 & \infty & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & \{4,5,6,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 12 & \infty & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & \{4,5,7\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 12 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & \{4,5\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & \{5\} & 0 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 12 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{center}
```

you get much better (in my opinion) output

[image]

And even better without `\boldmath`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. \tikz together with \graph was indeed the crux of the problem. I wonder if you could expound on your first statement? What does it mean that it might send the tabular somewhere else? What is then the purpose of the table envorinment?

Comment: @Alakanu: ```table``` is a class of floats. Floats are not typeset in sequence with the normal text but instead are floated to a convenient place, such as the top of a following page.

Comment: So, following the same reasoning, should I also avoid the figure environment for my tikzpicture?

Comment: @Alakanu Yes, in this case you should avoid it. And indeed I didn't use it. Use `table` or `figure` only if there's a caption.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following options to `\graph` and remove the `\tikz` command like this:

```
\graph[tree layout, grow down, nodes={circle,draw}]
```

Then it moves it down:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Pictures
\usepackage{amsmath} % Maths formulas
\usepackage{float} % Figure placement
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Pretty graphs
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees, layered}

\title{Assignment 1}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle
\section{}
\subsection*{a.}
In the following table, the first row corresponds to the setup step of Dijkstra's algorithm and the other rows correspond to the state during each iteration of the for loop in the algorithm.
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
            \textbf{$\#$} & \textbf{T} & \textbf{$u_1$} & \textbf{$u_2$} & \textbf{$u_3$} & \textbf{$u_4$} & \textbf{$u_5$} & \textbf{$u_6$} & \textbf{$u_7$} & \textbf{$P_1$} & \textbf{$P_2$} & \textbf{$P_3$} & \textbf{$P_4$} & \textbf{$P_5$} & \textbf{$P_6$} & \textbf{$P_7$}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{0} & \textbf{$\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{1} & \textbf{$\{3,4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{1}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{2} & \textbf{$\{4,5,6,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{$\infty$} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{3} & \textbf{$\{4,5,7\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{4} & \textbf{$\{4,5\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{5} & \textbf{$\{5\}$} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}


This is the resulting spanning tree:
\newline
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \graph[tree layout, grow down, nodes={circle,draw}]
          {
            1 -- {2,3};
            2 -- 6 -- 5;
            3 -- 7 -- 4;
         };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want the tree diagram in the centre like this:

[image]

use this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \graph[tree layout, grow down, nodes={circle,draw}]
          {
            1 -- {2,3};
            2 -- 6 -- 5;
            3 -- 7 -- 4;
         };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I recommend: ```\centering```.

Comment: Indeed that is better, thank you, not sure why I went with the longer way!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. \tikz and \graph was indeed the problem. An earlier answer also solved the problem so I will mark that one as the solution, sorry.

Comment: I just want to add in general that I posted this answer roughly at the same time as the accepted one, if not slightly before as there was no answer when I posted this.